# How to deal with CI pipeline duplication in micro services (or applications) - specifically Jenkinsfile's?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I was wondering how people deal with duplication between micro services (or applications) in CI pipelines (in Jenkinsfile's particularly). Is this an issue that should be addressed (and if so any suggestions?). I like having services that are more independent but I can see how they could be considered duplicate code.

**Questions:**

- Is this a problem that needs to be addressed?

  - If so, how do other people solve it?
  - If so, how far do you go with it/how much do you do (flexibility vs duplication)?

**Ideas:**

**Idea 1 - Jenkins Libraries:**

One method could be a common Jenkins library repository, but it feels like it would create a heavily coupling between services (thus harder to update and go forward).

I can see two approaches to this:

1. A couple of lines (import library, then run a shared function e.g. mvnSharedPipeline()) - this was suggested but it feels too inflexible to me.
2. Each stage re-uses shared functions (or in parts of the stage) e.g. stage "build" would call the shared mvnBuild Function or something - Basically: https://medium.com/@jackrwstevenson/the-reusable-microservice-pipeline-pattern-41742b2e640a

**Idea 2 - Docker files:**

Another approach I can think of is to use Docker containers.

I can see two ways:

1. A tools container built on top of something like OpenJdk# container with custom scripts added e.g. "Name/OpenJdk8ToolsContainer"
2. A general CI tools Docker Container but call specific containers for specific tasks (e.g. `docker run --rm ..pwd volume mount.. mvn build` and `docker run Name/CustomToolsContainer --rm ...pwd volume mount... lintJsonFiles.sh`)

**My Thoughts:**

One of my concerns is with how dependant a project is on the CI environment e.g. what version of Java/PHP/etc they have installed in the CI itself. I have seen companies stuck on older versions of languages due to a large time required to test/update everything all at once, so I am leaning towards the Docker approach (2) myself. Personally, I prefer to run everything I can in containers especially with CI. Unfortunately I have lost a lot of time debugging why something only works/does not work on in CI's (not Jenkins), so I am very attracted to replicability/re-usability between CI and development environment.

I am also under the mindset that a CI pipeline is never perfect nor finished, there will always be things that can be added/updated e.g. to improve quality or a version update. So I can see CI pipelines diverging, then being normalised as a common action - but I am willing to be corrected!

Comment: HI , 

we used Idea 1 - Jenkins Libraries , and add some parameters to have some flexibility.

Comment: Hi @MorLajb, thanks - that's an idea